# Mixed radio buttons and text boxes: What is the sane way to navigate with a keyboard?

Tags: windows, winforms, user-interface

I have a windows form, shown below.  Some of the radio options require additional information (2 & 3) before the button press, some do not.

[image]

The problem is this: how is this supposed to be navigated with a keyboard?

By default the behavior is:

- Focus is in radioButton1
- Down-arrow goes to radioButton2
- Down-arrow again goes to... textbox1

At this point, down-arrow goes nowhere else.  Tab will go to textbox2, then button1.

radioButton3 is **unreachable** via the keyboard.

Excluding textbox1 and textbox2 from the tab ordering (TabStop = False) makes radioButton3 accessible, but now the text boxes are no longer reachable.

I have tried:

- Excluding textbox1 and textbox2 from tab ordering (now they're unreachable)
- Catching down-arrow in textbox1 and having focus travel to radioButton3 (this feels very wrong, and presents a maintenance headache).
- Disabling textbox1 and textbox2 unless the corresponding radio is checked. (Nope, this actually manages to make things much worse)

What I don't want to consider:

- A prompt after the button for the needed text.  (sounds kludgey)
- A single text box below the radio buttons.  (in this app, the text boxes all have different validations, so what a pain).
- A mouse is required (not an option)

What's the correct way to handle this?

Comment: What order do you _want_ the down arrow key to cycle through the controls? One way would be to override `ProcessCmdKey` to only have have the arrow keys move between the radio buttons, and then when you select one that has a textbox, automatically place the cursor in it.

Comment: I would have expected (and wanted) the arrow to continue through the radio buttons and not suddenly act like a tab was pressed after the second button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `TabIndex` for radioButton1 thru radioButton4 so they go from 0 (zero) to 3.

Make the `TabIndex` for textBox1 and textBox2, 4 and 5 respectively.

The Button should be `TabIndex` 6.

Now the RadioButtons can be navigated with up/down arrows, and you can Tab from the TextBoxes thru the Button and back to the RadioButtons.

*If you placed all the RadioButtons first, then the TextBoxes, then the TabIndexes would be setup this way.  You probably initially placed the controls in this order: radioButton1, radioButton2, textBox1, radioButton3, textBox2, radioButton4, button1

Comment: This does actually get to all of the controls, however it seems kinda of wrong that to get to the corresponding text box for a radio button it's necessary to go all the way around....

Comment: Agreed; it is wonky.  ...but I think this is the "correct" way to do it if you do **not** want to add code into the mix.